# Attaching database to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, database

I accidentally upgraded an empty SQL Server 2014 database by Visual Studio 2015. After that I couldn't attach database.

Even I tried with SQL Server 2016 and SQL Server 2019 to downgrade but every time I get this message:

> The database 'E:\RADIOSOFTWARE\DBMICROWAVE.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 852. This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.

How can I solve that?

Total size of the database is 7.0MB

Thanks

Comment: Once the SQL Server database file is at a certain version, it **cannot** be "downgraded" anymore to be attached to other (earlier) versions of SQL Server. Either you use the same version of SQL Server on all machines involved, or you have to start using SQL scripts to move structural and data changes from one version of the SQL Server database to the other

Comment: The SQL Server is backwards for compatible with the MDF file if it is attached to the Server.  You are probably using LocalDb which is a driver that is not backwards forward compatible.  Is you database attached to a server?  Then do not use the attach database in the connection string with the mdf file.  The connection string should use the Server and Instance in the connection string.  Open SQL Server Management and check server instance name i login window.  The use same in the connection string.  And remove the ATTACH from connection string.

Comment: I don't know why I can't attach Db to 2016  or 2019 servers ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to  downgrade a SqlServer 2016 DataBase I generated script from " tasks "  in Microsoft sqlserver 2016 and in Advanced options I selected " script for server version 2014 ". Then I opened the script in SqlServer 2014 . That's It .
thanks